# Unable to Select Text within Clickable Card Component in Next.js

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I have a clickable card component wrapped in the <`Link`> component in a Next.js project. Inside the card, I have a title and some text. However, I am facing an issue where I cannot select text within the card for copying.

```
    // CardComponent.js
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';

const CardComponent = ({ title, text, link }) => {
  return (
    <Link href={link}>
        <div className="card">
          <h2>{title}</h2>
          <p>{text}</p>
        </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default CardComponent;
```

I've tried adjusting CSS properties like `user-select:text`, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Any insights or suggestions on how to make the text within the card selectable for copying would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Link is used to navigate through pages. How you want this component to behave? Since its a Link component, it redirect you to the href link provided on click.

Comment: I need to have <Link> functionality, like navigate to internal link, the problem that I am not able to select/copy separate parts of card content (for example title) , because it wrapped into <Link>

Comment: that wont work, because click always trigger navigation.  why you want to copy since its a link